# Regular expression is overwriting CSS styles in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I am using regular expressions to make a parts of the list bold. Actually everything bold before the colon. But the regular expressions are overwriting my css styles. I want that the css styles are displayed.

I know that the regular expressions are overwriting my CSS, because when I remove the regular expression the CSS styles will appear. I have tried to use `!important` next to the hex. But that didn't work. Do I need to change the regular expression. Or do I need to add a new line of code?

```
<ul>
 <li>Apple: Has the color <span style="background-color:#FF0000">red</span></li>
 <li>Orange: Has the color <span style="background-color:#FFAE00">orange</span></li>
 <li>Banana: Has the color yellow</li>
 <li>Blackberries: Has the color purple</li>
 <li>Avocado: Has the color green</li>
</ul>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   let list = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
   list.forEach((element) => {
     element.innerHTML = element.innerText.replace(/^[^:]+:/, '<b>$&</b>');
     
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are taking `innerText` and put it into `innerHTML`, you simply stripping off all the HTML from it.

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
list.forEach((element) => {
 element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/^[^:]+:/, '<b>$&</b>');
});
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>Apple: Has the color <span style="background-color:#FF0000">red</span></li>
 <li>Orange: Has the color <span style="background-color:#FFAE00">orange</span></li>
 <li>Banana: Has the color yellow</li>
 <li>Blackberries: Has the color purple</li>
 <li>Avocado: Has the color green</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now that I can see the code it makes more sense to use innerHTML instead of using innerText. Thanks your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the style `fontWeight = "bold"` on each element?

```html
<ul>
 <li>Apple: Has the color <span style="background-color:#FF0000">red</span></li>
 <li>Orange: Has the color <span style="background-color:#FFAE00">orange</span></li>
 <li>Banana: Has the color yellow</li>
 <li>Blackberries: Has the color purple</li>
 <li>Avocado: Has the color green</li>
</ul>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   let list = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
   list.forEach((element) => {
     element.style.fontWeight = "bold"
});
     
 </script>
```